# How did Riemann calculate the first few non-trivial zeros of the zeta-function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Does anyone know how Riemann calculated the first few non-trivial zeros of the Zeta function?  I am wondering if he approximated the integral, $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{R} \frac{{\xi}^\prime(z)}{\xi (z)} dz$ over appropriate rectangle(s) in the critical strip.  This still seems difficult, however, without a computer.

Comment: see http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417409.html  especially reproduction on page 156 and discussion of Riemann's hand calculations from about 155-162

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In searching through the Riemann Nachlass in Gottingen (including those
folders not listed as connected with  $\zeta(s)) $ there is no
evidence -- at least that has been saved -- that Riemann computed
anything more than the first few zeros (I think up to ordinate about 80).
The method he used was the expansion that is now called the Riemann-Siegel
formula.  I did not see any use, e.g., of an approach based on
Euler-Maclaurin.   The limited accuracy Riemann obtained reflects that of
the error term in the R-S formula.

Answer (score 5):

"Know" is hard for those of us without a ouija board, but I think people believe that the [Riemann-Siegel](http://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/six/parallel/2-Final-Report.html) formula was used.

Comment: I'm looking at Edward's book, this is discussed in pages 155-162 and on. He reproduces the page with the formula from the Gottingen Library.